# PYTHON - Restart same for loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I need some help here.

I have this for loop

```
for i in range(0,15):
        logging.info('-----  packing iteration %i started  ------' % (i))
        po_selection_list = po_sel.get_po_lists(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials,TrayName,i) # get po lists for this iteration
        po_count = 0
        for po_list in po_selection_list: # loop through all lists
            if len(po_list) == 0: #if list is empty go to next list
                pass
            else: # else load po's in tray
                po_count += len(po_list)
                functions_library.AddPOs_Stage1(po_list,driver)
                functions_library.AddPOs_trayIDSearch(driver)
                functions_library.AddPOs_Stage2(driver)

                functions_library.ImportParts()
        if po_count == 0: # if no po's were loaded in the tray go to next iteration
            pass
        else: # else pack and sync in netfabb
            functions_library.MovePartsZHeight()
            functions_library.NetfabbPacking(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials)
            functions_library.RemoveNetfabbExtraParts()
            functions_library.NetfabbSync(driver)
```

Imagine if we are running in iteration number 4.
What I need is if **functions_library.AddPOs_trayIDSearch(driver)** returns **False** I want to restart the loop again (iteration number 4)

**EDIT**

```
for i in range(0,15):
    logging.info('-----  packing iteration %i started  ------' % (i))
    po_selection_list = po_sel.get_po_lists(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials,TrayName,i) # get po lists for this iteration
    po_count = 0
    for po_list in po_selection_list: # loop through all lists
        if len(po_list) == 0: #if list is empty go to next list
            pass
        else: # else load po's in tray
            po_count += len(po_list)
            functions_library.AddPOs_Stage1(po_list,driver)
            functions_library.AddPOs_trayIDSearch(driver)
            functions_library.AddPOs_Stage2(driver)

            functions_library.ImportParts()
    if po_count: # if no po's were loaded in the tray go to next iteration
        functions_library.MovePartsZHeight()
        functions_library.NetfabbPacking(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials)
        functions_library.RemoveNetfabbExtraParts()
        functions_library.NetfabbSync(driver)

### finish the tray ###
functions_library.SelectAll(TrayHeight)
functions_library.MovePartsZHeight()
functions_library.NetfabbPacking(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials)
functions_library.RemoveNetfabbExtraParts()
functions_library.RemoveCylinders(TrayHeight)
functions_library.NetfabbSync(driver)
functions_library.SetToPrinting(driver)
functions_library.SaveJob(tray_folder,TrayName)
functions_library.NetfabbSlicing(TrayID,tray_folder,TrayName)
logging.info('Tray: '+TrayName+' done!')
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `continue`? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: No because I don't want to skip to iteration 5, I want to re-run iteration 4.

Comment: I don't see where the variable `driver` comes from. Does it change its value every iteration? The code example as provided doesn't make sense, because if the value for `driver` doesn't change you'll create an endless loop, iterating all the time for 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering, note that:

```
if something == 0:
    pass
else:
    do_stuff()
```

can be simplified into:

```
if something:
    do_stuff()
```

because Python interprets it as `if bool(something) == True: do_stuff()`.

For your actual question, you could use a `while` loop and increment a counter only if the call you’re interested in returns `True`. You can check that every calls succeded using the [`for ... else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=else#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct:

```
i = 0
while i < 15:
    logging.info('-----  packing iteration %i started  ------' % (i))
    po_selection_list = po_sel.get_po_lists(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials,TrayName,i) # get po lists for this iteration
    po_count = 0
    for po_list in po_selection_list: # loop through all lists
        if po_list: # load po's in tray
            po_count += len(po_list)
            functions_library.AddPOs_Stage1(po_list,driver)
            if not functions_library.AddPOs_trayIDSearch(driver):
                break
            functions_library.AddPOs_Stage2(driver)

            functions_library.ImportParts()
    else:
        # break didn't occur
        if po_count: # pack and sync in netfabb
            functions_library.MovePartsZHeight()
            functions_library.NetfabbPacking(TrayID,TrayHeight,Materials)
            functions_library.RemoveNetfabbExtraParts()
            functions_library.NetfabbSync(driver)
        i += 1
```

Comment: It can be simplified to `if a != 0: do_stuff()`. You have a slight error in the beginning.

Comment: @cezar `if a: do_stuff()` is more generic than `if a != 0: do_stuff()` as it accounts for all truthy values, not only integer ones. Check the `if po_list` in the code to understand.

Comment: I meant `something`, just took `a` as shortcut. In order to simplify the if-clause you have to negate the condition.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When comparing to 0, we can check for truthy (or falsy) values. I was thinking in general, not concerning the 0 in particular. But that `pass` in the if-clause immediately caught my eye. It definitely doesn't belong there. It's very good to point that out.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that I would break the `for po_list` only. I also want the `while loop`to stop that iteration and start again. I think this wasn't totally clear because I missed some of the code. I will edit the post now

Comment: @TiagoSãoJosé well, it will… As soon as the `break` is encountered, the `for` loop exits. Since the for loop exited with a `break` statement, the `else` clause won't be executed. Thus reaching the end of the `while` loop… without incrementing `i`. So a soon as the `break` is reached the `while` loop will start again at the same iteration.

Comment: That makes sense!!! Sorry for the confusion! Thanks a lot! I will test it but it looks that will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not easier to use `while` iterator?

```
c = 0
while c < 5:
    ...
    result = functions_library.AddPOs_trayIDSearch(...)
    if not result:
        c = 0
    else:
        c -= 1
```